# C#.net WinForms how to causes text in textbox to disappear when textbox is on focus?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

is there a way in which i could create light grey text that disappears when a textbox is on focus?

Currently, i have text written in the textbox but i have to select the text and manually delete it (somewhat annoying...)

I know i can do something when i get focus on the box (using events) however, i don't want it to clear the text every time the user selects that box... rather just the first time. In other words, i just want the hint text to disappear (not the text they enter if they were to select the box after typing in it once)...

I also realize i could use something like a counter to keep track of if it's the first time that box is being clicked on.. however, i was looking for a cleaner way to do this.....

Comment: Add an event listener for focus, then remove it the first time it's called

Comment: based on your edit... why not use the onform load?

Comment: @Tom Bass, yea, i could do that i guess. I guess i was thinking more of how it's done in js and how clean it is. It's one line of code and it does exactly that. The cool thing about it is that when you click off the box (if you haven't entered anything) it goes back to the hint-text. I can do this here too... but it just seems like there should be a cleaner way. Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the code below.
Please note, this is not a compiled code. Just sharing the idea, plus you may like to retain the default settings if user did not enter any text. For that handle a lost focus  and reset to default.

```
   public class FancyTextBox : TextBox{

private bool _isDefaultText;
public FancyTextBox(){
     UpdateDefaultSettings(true);         
}

protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnGotFocus(e);
    UpdateDefaultSettings(false);
}

protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLostFocus(e);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
    {
        //Retain Default Setting.
        UpdateDefaultSettings(true);
    }
}

private void UpdateDefaultSettings(bool isDefault){
    _isDefaultText = isDefault;
    if(_isDefaultText){
       Text = "Please enter";
       this.ForeColor= Color.Gray;  
    }
    else{
       Text = "";
       ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

A simpler answer is

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, uint wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);

public static void SetHint(TextBox textBox, string hintText)
{
 const uint EmSetCueBanner = 0x1501;
 SendMessage(textBox.Handle, EmSetCueBanner, 0, hintText);
}
```